# Over-confident model predictions causing all-0 gradients

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

Currently I'm implementing GradCAM (activation heatmap) for my CNN model. It works perfectly when my confidence isn't 100% (note: it's a multi-label classification problem, so I'm using sigmoid activation, not softmax).

However, when my model is overly confident (literally confidence of 1.0 (100%)) the gradient of my final output layer w.r.t my final convolution's output feature map becomes all-zero.

I assume this may be because in order to have 100% the loss must be 0 or near-0. I've tried several approaches on the loss tensor to account for this including clipping, normalization (both hard-coded and using tensorflow's l2_norm function), and simply adding a very small float to it (1e-5).

However, nothing has worked and I've been unable to find any resources on the topic. Am I missing a very simple trick or function that could be helpful? Or is this a deeper problem of my model's architecture?

TLDR; How can I normalize / tune my model's output loss tensor such that it contains no 0 values?

Comment: why would you use sigmoid for multi-label instead of softmax? that does not make sense.

Comment: because each sample can belong to one or more classes. I understood softmax to produce values which always sum to 1, which isn't a desired behavior for my model.